# Less colors in rgba() even if alpha channel is 1

Tags: less

I need that Less compiler don't convert to HEX colors defined in rgba(), **even if alpha channel is 1**

Actually, the following Less code:

```
@color1: rgba(0,0,0,1);
@color2: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
@color1_light: lighten(@color1,90%);
@color2_light: lighten(@color2,90%);

.a {
  background:@color1;
  color: @color1_light;
}

.b {
  background:@color2;
  color: @color2_light;
}
```

is processed to:

```
.a {
  background: #000000;
  color: #e6e6e6;
}
.b {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.1);
}
```

but I need to have (for many reasons related to further evaluations)

```
.a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 1);
}
.b {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.1);
}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is pretty easy, all you have to do is to escape your expression, below you will find two examples how to force less compiler to display rgba format even though alpha is 1:

```
@color1: rgba(0,0,0,1);

body {
    color: ~"rgba("red(@color1), green(@color1), blue(@color1),~" 1)";
    background: %(~"rgba(%s, %s, %s, 1)", red(@color1), green(@color1), blue(@color1));
}
```

Both examples will produce `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)`, it's up to you which one do you prefer. I bet you will find more info in the docs under `string escape` and `string replace`

> //EDIT

yup, this is tricky, but still, you can extend this with a mixin so it won't look that bad in code hereafter.

```
@color1: rgba(0,0,0,1);

.rgba(@color) {
    //@rgba: ~"rgba("red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color),~" 1)";
    @rgba: %(~"rgba(%s, %s, %s, %s)", red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), alpha(@color));
}

.torgba(@property, @color) {
    @{property}: %(~"rgba(%s, %s, %s, %s)", red(@color1), green(@color1), blue(@color1), alpha(@color1));
}

body {
    .rgba(@color1); // mixin returns @rgba variable that may be used later on, it's not color object however, but a string
    color: @rgba;
    background: @rgba;
    .torgba(border-color, @color1); // do the same, but returns property with color in given format
}
```

Comment: tricky... everytime that I have to use this color, I have to write all this value? I hoped that some function in LESS package could output the right syntax...

Comment: @LucaDetomi - yup, still, you can extend it somehow with for example mixins, like in the edit above.

Comment: @LucaDetomi if the answer fixes your problem please consider accepting it